# Build Dynamic FormBuilder in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formgroups

I have created an Angular project with Dynamic Inputs, I click on a button then new inputs create and I want to use FormBuilder to get the data but I don't know how to do this.

I know how to use FormBuilder in the static case but I didn't find any resource for dynamic.

Which are the steps to follow to achieve that?

Comment: do you want to get the form data whenever a new input is added? And is it only an input thats added or a formgroup?

Comment: just inputs e.g: when I click on add button two inputs will be appears one for the first name and the other for lastname and so on, I think it's the same formgroup

Answer (score 2):

How are you adding new inputs to the existing formgroup? For example you can do this by using form arrays, and basically with that you are able to gate de value from it just by accessing like: formGroup.get("formArray").value -> you will get all the inputs value by one shot.

Comment: I never used the form arrays before, I will check that

Answer (score 1):

Im not too sure if this is what you meant but if you wanted to add new inputs everytime user clicks button and get the value then you could try this. expanding on @ZsoltB answer
working [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkgqck)

```
@Component({
  ...all the decorator things
})
export class AppComponent {
  formArray = new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
    }),
  ]);
  name = 'angular';

  addNewInput = () => {
    this.formArray.push(
      new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl(''),
        lastName: new FormControl(''),
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using and inspired by the following code :

[dynamic form in angular, add fields on runtime](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjqhl8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

thank you very much